# How do I print a text file in .net

Tags: vb.net, printing

How do I print a .txt file in vb.net? Hopefully without using any third parties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this example on how to print files with VB.Net: [MSDN How to: Print a Multi-Page Text File in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d.aspx)

The most important class you need is [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx). No third party tools or Dll's other than in System.Drawing and System.IO Namespace in .Net-Framework(> 1.1) are needed.

Answer (score 4):

See [How to print batch file in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435644/how-to-print-batch-file-in-vb-net). There's a VB.NET code sample which you should be able to use verbatim.

If you don't already know how to pull text out of a file, use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx), like this:

```
Imports System.IO
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt"
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("WindowsPrinterName", File.ReadAllText(path))
```

`RawPrinterHelper` is the class described in the other question linked above.  "WindowsPrinterName" is the name of the printer you want to print to.