# Print File(NotePad) Without the name of the file appearing in the printing document

Tags: windows, vb.net, command-line, command-prompt

```
Dim ProcessProperties As New ProcessStartInfo()
ProcessProperties.FileName = "notepad.exe"
ProcessProperties.Arguments = "/p c:/doc.txt" 'command line arguments ''
''ProcessProperties.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(ProcessProperties)
```

when printing using the code above i have "doc.txt" printed. I don't want the file name to appear when printing is over

Comment: You cannot easily modify the way Notepad prints a text file.  There just isn't any need to hand this job over to Notepad, use the PrintDocument class instead to print it the way you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to pass an argument through command line to notepad to hide the header, the only parameter accepted for the /P argument is the file name. (See [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389?msgId=6ef465b1-d6bd-4d34-83f0-fae12ae7df2c))

The only way to hide the header from printing is by opening notepad and going to File->Page Setup, and changing the header command. (See [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/78790))

If it is really needed to print using a process, you can try searching for third party editing tools which support printing arguments.

Another way is to implement functionality for printing the text file, see this Stackoverflow article ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763029/how-do-i-print-a-text-file-in-net))

Answer (score 1):

You will have to configure the header and footer options of Notepad in order to prevent or override the file name appearing on the print page. This can be done by simulating user input to bring up the Page Setup dialog and clear the header and footer.

There are a number of ways to send user input (mouse and/or keyboard). For starters you could look at these two:

- [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)
- [Application and Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks .Net Libary in C#](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/)